# Correct way to make a schedule

Tags: php, date

I've been debating whether to use Date functions or just whether there is a cleaner way to make an array of a given day's minutes at the moment my code reads like this;

```
 function emptySchedule()
    {
        $emptySchedule = [];
        for ($h = 0; $h < 24; ++$h) {
            for ($m = 0; $m < 60; ++$m) {
                $emptySchedule[str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)] = [];
            }
        }

        return $emptySchedule;
    }
```

But it just feels **dirty**, is there a better way to achieve the same result or maybe a better way to handle the minutes in the day with a date object or even better a globally accepted **correct** way? I'd prefer not to use a package, but if there is a good one I'm open to it.

**EDIT**; for some context, I will be putting arrays into each minute of the day.

**EDIT2**: for the purpose of what this will be used for there is no need for any input, my final function was;

```
public function emptySchedule()
{
    $startDate = date_create("today"); //Any start date works
    $endDate = date_create("tomorrow"); //Any end date works
    $step = new \DateInterval("PT1M"); //1 minute, can change
    $date = $startDate;
    $times = [];
    while ($date <= $endDate) {
        $times[$date->format("H:i")] =  [];
        $date = $date->add($step);
    }

    return $times;
}
```

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours…! For that reason alone you should be using date functions.

Comment: Ah daylight saving time didn't occur to me, I'm completely lost as to how I'd solve that problem, maybe need a fresh morning with my coffee, I'm in the last hour at work so pretty tired out!!

Comment: Robert, show to us an example of desirable output to help with solution, please.

Comment: @calexandre literally everything is in the question :p. I'm unsure of best practices but **I will be putting arrays into each minute of the day** (see Edit, i guess you missed it :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

```
$startDate = date_create("today"); //Any start date works
$endDate = date_create("tomorrow"); //Any end date works
$step = new DateInterval("PT1M"); //1 minute, can change
$date = $startDate;
$times = [];
while ($date <= $endDate) {
      $times[$date->format("H:i")] =  [];
      $date = $date->add($step);
}

print_r($times);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd91a8f3f1707ca20aae93f70969275d5fb8dedd

Answer (score 1):

Well, a more elegant approach of your code is:

```
<?php
function emptySchedule($hoursInit = date('G'), $hoursActive = 24)
    {
        $emptySchedule = [];
        for ($h = $hoursInit; $h < $hoursActive; ++$h) {
           for ($m = 0; $m < 60; ++$m) {
             $emptySchedule[sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m)] = [];
           }  
        }

        return $emptySchedule;
}
```

You can use interval too, working with lunch hours in your schedule and stuff:

```
<?php
function emptySchedule($hoursInit = date('G'), $hoursActive = 24, $interval = false)
    {
        $emptySchedule = [];
        for ($h = $hoursInit; $h < $hoursActive; ++$h) {
            if ($interval && ($h < $interval['start'] || $h > $interval['end'])) {
              for ($m = 0; $m < 60; ++$m) {
                $emptySchedule[sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m)] = [];
              }
            }

        }

        return $emptySchedule;
}
```

But, like @deceze said, using date functions is a must, it's not simple to do right now, I'll try to figure out a better way;

Comment: I think a combination of your answer and the one below is probably the "clean" approach I'm looking for, shame I can't accept 2 answers :(!